# connecting custom FPGA to a pool

Tags: mining-pools

I have created an FPGA with a C function wrapper that accepts the Ethereum header and difficulty and returns the calculated hash value. I want to connect this FPGA to one of the Ethereum mining pools, any idea how to do it? Is there a mining pool that provides some sort of an API that allows calling custom C functions?

Comment: Mining pools usually use stratum protocol.